# android- crashing application while switching between activities

Tags: android

**I have edit the manifest file as well. and did everything i could do. still my code is crashing. please help me with this error..............................................................................................**

Activity 1(MainActivity):

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

button3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {    
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        Intent act2 = new Intent(view.getContext(),welcomemessage.class);
        startActivity(act2);
    }
});
```

Acitivity 2(welcomemessage):

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);`
setContentView(R.layout.activity_welcomemessage);

TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button4);
btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        Intent act1 = new Intent(view.getContext(), MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(act1);    
    }
});
```

manifestfile:

```
<activity
    android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">

    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />    
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>

<activity
    android:name=".welcomemessage"
    android:label="@string/app_name">    
</activity>
```

layouts name are: Layout 1(acitivity_main) and 
layout 2(activity_welcomemessgae)

Comment: What does the crash say? Maybe you should post your stack trace here?

Comment: Why using view.getContext()? Use the class name in which your intent is placed.

Answer (score 1):

All java classes have to be capitalized, welcomemessage is not and in the mainfest it needs an intent filter block as well, if you post the logcat I can help track down any other errors

Answer (score 0):

can you post the error log? 
it will be easier to solve the error if we know it.

you can try these steps:

step 1: 
clean the project

Project >> clean >> clean projects selected below >> choose your project

step 2:
try this one:

```
button3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub



     Intent intent=new Intent(MainActivity.this,welcomemessage.class);
        startActivity(intent);




        }

        });
```